# Java Assign the concrete implementation object at runtime

Tags: java, oop, runtime

I was reading the book Head First Design Patterns in section programming to a supertype.
The book explains that the best practice would be to use the function getAnimal().
Doubt:

- How to actually implement the a = getAnimal() function? I tested what I understood, however I am not sure if I got it right.

Below is the excerpt of the book:
[image]

"Programming to an implementation would be:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
d.bark();
```

But programming to an interface/supertype would be:

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
animal.makeSound();
```

Even better, rather than hardcoding the instantiation of the
subtype (like new Dog()) into the code, assign the concrete
implementation object at runtime:

```
a = getAnimal();
a.makeSound();
```

"

Here is what I have so far, however I am not sure if I got the concept clearly, would this type of implementation be what the book means?

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract void makeSound();
}
```

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
    void bark(){
        System.out.println("Bark");
    }

    @Override
    void makeSound() {
        bark();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Animal animal=new Dog();
        animal.makeSound();
    }
        
}
```

```
public class ConcreteAnimal extends Animal {
    Animal animal;

    @Override
    void makeSound() {
        animal.makeSound();
    }

    Animal getAnimal() {
        Animal dog = new Dog();// Is this correct?
        return dog;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteAnimal ca = new ConcreteAnimal();
        Animal a = ca.getAnimal();// How to call getAnimal() without an object nor class name?
        a.makeSound();//It prints the Bark as expected.
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: *"Is this correct?"* Yes, or simply use `return new Dog();`. --- *"How to call getAnimal() without an object nor class name?"* Make the method `static` and call it without a qualifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a factory method pattern to create Animal objet. Use AnimalFactoryDemo class instead of ConcreteAnimal class. It should look something like this:

```
public class AnimalFactoryDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      Animal animal = AnimalFactory.getAnimal("Dog");
      animal.makeSound();
    }
}

public class AnimalFactory 
{
   public static Animal getAnimal(String Animal) 
   {
     if (type.equals("Dog"))
        return new Dog();
     else if (type.equals("Cat"))
        return new Cat();
     else
        return null;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Note this is the [Static Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info) pattern. It is entirely different from the GoF [Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/factory-method/info) pattern.